# Are there still oceans on the darkened Matrix Earth?

Tags: the-matrix

In the first Matrix film, we see how Morpheus shows Anderson the devastated Earth, first from a TV screen, then like being actually there, looking on a city that looks like New York (the destroyed buildings look like the former WTCs). If it's indeed New York, it looks like they're watching it from a dried out Atlantic Ocean. Throughout the 2nd and 3rd film, the *Logos* goes from Zion to the Machine City eventually, leaving the underground tunnels close to the machine city and the fields and towers of the bluepills. Since I suspect Zion somewhere beneath North America and the Machine City is in Mesopotamia, either the tunnels are so deep they go beneath the Atlantic Ocean or there are no more oceans on the Matrix Earth.

It is assumed that Zion isn't "close to the Earth's core" as Tank put it, but much closer to the surface. Throughout the trilogy no surface water is seen (outside the Matrix), so are there no more oceans on the Matrix Earth and if so, how did that happen?

Comment: *"Since Zion is in Northern America*" - Citation required.

Comment: @Valorum After the Operation Dark Storm's failure, the war ended in New York, for the time being. Since all surviving humans in Morpheus' time speak English, and the matrix is set in a futuristic version of Chicago, Zion quite sure is somewhere beneath either New York or Chicago or elswhere beneath former U.S. territory. It would be quite a surprise if Zion is below another continent.

Comment: Since all of the people in Zion learned English from *inside the Matrix*, it really doesn't follow that Zion must be in America, simply because everyone speaks English. Similarly, the Matrix also includes simulations of [Japan](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Beyond) (where they speak Japanese), and [London](https://twitter.com/i/status/907698683386269697).

Comment: @Valorum But in Zion all speak English. The first Zion obviously was founded when the war ended in New York. I assume that after the UN headquarters were blown up, the surviving Americans founded the first Zion beneath NYC. But you're right that the following Zions could have been built elsewhere each.

Comment: Except Zion was founded by the machines? It functions as a sort of pressure valve for the instability in the matrix. When it reaches critical mass, the one emerges, meets the architect, the machines destroy Zion, then the one choses 23 individuals to rebuild it.

Comment: @ImmortalBlue Where did humans live between the end of the war and the creation of the first matrix? I mean, the sky was already darkened and the machines won so they had to live somewhere underground. In some proto-Zion perhaps.

Comment: @Betternottell - Humans didn't live anywhere between the end of the War and the creation of the Matrix. The machines were already developing it to power their war machines. As to where they live between being freed from the Matrix by the One and finding/founding Zion, I think we can be pretty sure that the Machines just pretend to ignore them for a bit and give them sneaky access to food and supplies.

Comment: "Since all surviving humans in Morpheus' time speak English, and the matrix is set in a futuristic version of Chicago, Zion quite sure is somewhere beneath either New York or Chicago or elswhere beneath former U.S. territory" — I think you mean "speak *American* English" — if not, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, and a little place called the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland would like to point out some yawning chasms in your logic.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, I mean _English_ because Valorum mentioned Japan.

Comment: @Betternottell: that's great that someone mentioned Japan, it doesn't make what you said accurate.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Read my entire comment again to learn why "speaking English" is not the only reason why I supposed Zion is beneath North America.

Comment: @Betternottell: that still doesn't make your "English" comment any more accurate. America is not the only country in the world that speaks English.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I love your country, believe me, I love Britain very much. But it would be more a surprise if Zion was beneath Britain than beneath America. I get your point of course but I can't do anything about it.

Comment: Do people in Zion *really* speak English? Or are you just *watching a movie in English*? [Translation Convention](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention) is a thing, y'know...

Comment: @Matthew No, I'm watching it in another language, but English must be the language of Zion if it is also the language inside the Matrix whose "capital city" (as seen on Anderson's ID-card) is the futuristic version of Chicago.  I don't say it _is_ like I claim, it's just my opinion.

Comment: ...but the movie was *filmed* in English (i.e. was produced by people who spoke English, primarily for an English-speaking audience, and using English-speaking actors), and it's harder to redo visual imagery than to dub audio. Point is, there are plenty of Doylist reasons to use English that don't necessarily mean English is the *in universe* language. OTOH, if you want a Watsonian reason, English may simply have been the dominant world language at the time (as it more-or-less is in real life).

Comment: @betternottell: sir — you could acknowledge your mistake, delete your comment, and pledge your allegiance to Queen and Commonwealth immediately.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But the rest of my comment would then be deleted too. I never wrote "The Zionese speak English and therefore Zion must be beneath America because only America speaks English." The English language is just a hint that Zion is _not_ beneath Japan, but I think now that Valorum is right and Zion might indeed be close to the machine city. And I won't pledge allegiance to the Queen as long as the mysterious death of Lady Diana isn't resolved.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the Animatrix short film '*Matriculated'* we open with our main character staring watchfully out to what we can assume is the sea. It follows that large expanses of open water are still around on the Earth.

[image]

As to the location of Zion, your question is at fault. We know from [*The Second Renaissance*](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Second_Renaissance) that the [Machine City](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/01) is in Mesopotamia. Since the Zionese hovercraft only seem to be capable of subsonic travel (and given that Neo and Trinity reach the city from Zion in only a few hours), it follows that Zion must also be relatively close by.

Comment: "it follows that Zion must also be relatively close by." Or the stories are mutually inconsistent...

Comment: Your claim they'e incapable of supersonic travel isn't sure either. And it wouldn't be very wise to build Zion too close to their enemy.

Comment: @Betternottell - We don't see them travel supersonically and their ships don't seem well designed for it. And if the plan is to recover people from the Matrix, they need to be relatively close to the Power Plant to do so, hence relatively close to Zero-One.

Comment: I thought the implication was that there is more than one power plant.  Indeed, since there are roughly 8 billion people living in the Matrix (it's basically same as the real world present-day population), it would be pretty much impossible for them to all be in one location.

Comment: @DarrellHoffman - It's certainly also.possible that the Machine City isn't Zero-One but another city entirely although I'd need a lot more convincing of that, given that it's explicitly confirmed to be the same place in the Matrix Online.

Comment: Aaah, I almost forgot that The Animatrix exists... Arigatou :D

Comment: @Betternottell According to the Architect in *Matrix:Reloaded*, keeping Zion out of reach of the machines wasn't a priority. Quite the contrary, in fact.

Comment: @Philipp - I think you have it backward. It was important to keep it safe, *until it was time to plough it under and replant.*

Comment: All 8 billion people on earth could - standing shoulder to shoulder - fit in an area the size of Rhode island https://what-if.xkcd.com/8/

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - It's worth noting that the human population (in the Matrix universe) is 6.5bn, not 8bn.

Comment: So a smaller area then . . .

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I was kind of thinking of that article myself.  Of course, Rhode Island may be the smallest state in the US, but it's still pretty big for a city (evidenced by the fact that there are in fact multiple cities within the state).  Also consider the impracticality of somehow powering the entire world with just one power plant in Rhode Island...

Answer (score 16):

I'm not aware of an unambiguous canonical answer, but some details in The Matrix comic "The Miller's Tale" by Paul Chadwick (included in the volume 1 collection) can be *read* as a **yes**.

Specifically, it describes the rain as unceasing, which seems unlikely without oceans to support a very active hydrologic cycle...

Here's an image of this page from [a partial/incomplete copy of it at the web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20040806174825/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/paulcMiller5a.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. I accepted Valorum's one just because her answer is directly showing it.

Comment: @Betternottell I don't think Valorum is a "she", but don't take my words on it. That's just the profile picture.

Comment: I wonder then who the woman on Valorum's profile image is. Is the upvoter of Clockwork's statement Valorum her-/himself? So far, Valorum didn't tell us here.

Comment: @Betternottell I think this is the answer to your comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/the-many-avatars-of-sff-se#comment28881_7694

Comment: @Betternottell But in case the link doesn't work properly, the comment says: "It's Buffy the Vampire Slayer."

Comment: @Clockwork Interesting. (however, in the link he/she doesn't tell if he/she's male or female but it doesn't matter)

Comment: I think that anyone who uses a female avatar intends to be referred to as "her". And there's always the chance that Valorum is Sarah Michelle Geller and that's her actual picture.